# How to generate smoke test cases for Java application using command line

Tags: java, maven, command-line-interface, cicd, smoke-testing

I wish to offer any new java based project to have basic/generic `smoke testing` as part of the CICD pipeline on github-actions or ansible.

Rather than having the developers write smoke test cases for their applications I wish to serve them with default test cases that are auto-generated by a tool or plugin.

One such plugin that I remember is [diffblue](https://www.diffblue.com)

It has github CICD integration example step as well.

I have a few challenges using its CLI (free license) and what it offers is why I wish to explore other options.

My repo structure is :

```
myrepo
  |--src
      |--classes
            |--common
                 |--com
                     |--mybank
                          |--common
                               |--hello1.class
                               |--hello2.class
                               |--util
                                    |--hello3.class
```

I tried to generate testcase java files which should as per documentation be generated at

```
myrepo
  |--src
      |--test
            |--java
```

1. `dcover -classpath "D:\maven\bin\mvn.bat" com.mybank.common.hello1` does not generate any test cases java file, does not throw any error as per logs either in `com.mybank.common` or in `src.test.java` folders.

Not sure what is wrong in my attempt to use the cli for a single java file or entire java repo project.

2. I wish to explore alternate tools that may offer more services or are more popular.

Note: this project was build using `ant` build.xml

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your repo code is not a Maven project. For the standalone maven batch file to work, your project needs to be completely maven project containing **pom.xml**.

**Note:** DiffBlue won't work with Ant based projects.

So, consider migrating your Ant based codebase to Maven based codebase to use DiffBlue tool.

---

From [Official DiffBlue Documentation](https://docs.diffblue.com/get-started/free-trial):

**Prerequisites**:

1. **Java 8 Update 351+**, **Java 11.0.17+** or **Java 17.0.5+** are supported at this moment.
2. Only **Maven 3.2.5+** or **Gradle 4.9+** build tools are supported.
3. Any project (for use with Diffblue Cover) must compile and run with no failing unit tests. **JUnit** and **TestNG** testing frameworks are supported.

Example on how DiffBlue works with Maven:

**Note:** I'm using Mac to show how it works. The process is similar for Windows as well.

1. Read the documentation from [here](https://docs.diffblue.com/get-started/beyond-the-trial-get-started/get-started-cover-cli) to setup DiffBlue CLI.
2. Execute `dcover version` to verify the DiffBlue installed or not.

   ```
   ➜  demo git:(master) ✗ dcover version
      2023.09.01-9200f07-licensed
   ```

I have a spring-boot based maven project with this structure below.

```
.
├── mvnw
├── mvnw.cmd
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── example
│   │   │           └── demo
│   │   │               ├── SampleController.java
│   │   │              
│   │   │               
│   │   │               
│   │   │  
│   │   │               
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.yml
│   │       ├── static
│   │       └── templates
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── example
│                   └── demo
                        └── empty <no test classes>
```

3. I have a SampleController class with an endpoint `divide`  which throws ArithmeticException:

   ```
   @RestController
   public class SampleController {

      @GetMapping("divide")
      public int divideByZero() throws ArithmeticException {
         int number = 2;
         return number / 0;
     }
   }
   ```
4. Enter root project directory with `cd` command.

**Note:** Execute the command from root directory itself as DiffBlue is smart enough to read all the classes and packages.

5. The command to generate the test is as follow :

   ```
   dcover create full-qualified-package-name.ClassName
   ```

Example: `dcover create com.example.demo.SampleController`

Current project structure contains the test class after dcover got executed:

```
.
├── mvnw
├── mvnw.cmd
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── example
│   │   │           └── demo
│   │   │               ├── SampleController.java
│   │   │              
│   │   │               
│   │   │               
│   │   │  
│   │   │               
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.yml
│   │       ├── static
│   │       └── templates
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── example
│                   └── demo
                        └── SampleControllerDiffblueTest.java
```

6. The test class generated from the above code is given below:

   ```
     package com.example.demo;

     import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
     import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
     import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

     class SampleControllerDiffblueTest {
        /**
         * Method under test: {@link SampleController#divideByZero()}
         */
         @Test
         void testDivideByZero() {
          assertThrows(ArithmeticException.class, () -> (new SampleController()).divideByZero());
        }
     }
   ```

Console Logs:

```
INFO  Diffblue Cover 2023.09.01-9200f07-licensed
INFO
INFO  Detecting environment:
INFO  ----------------------
INFO  Detected Java version 17.0.8
INFO  Selected build system: Maven
INFO  Selected classpath from build system Maven
INFO  Selected test framework: JUnit Jupiter
INFO  Selected Java language compliance level: 17
INFO  Selected test validation: enabled
INFO  Prefixes for filtering classes/methods:
INFO  - com.example.demo.SampleController
INFO  Gathering methods to test...
........
INFO
INFO  Creating tests:
INFO  ---------------
INFO  [1/1] com.example.demo.SampleController
INFO  [1/1]   Tests created: 1
INFO
INFO  Summary:
INFO  --------
INFO  Total:                                               2 methods
INFO  1 test created for:                                  1 method
INFO
INFO  Tested indirectly via other methods:                 1 method
INFO      1 T005: Trivial constructor
INFO
INFO  Running validation command.
INFO  This can take a couple of minutes.........
INFO  1 created test was successfully validated.
INFO  Log file: /Users/anish/Downloads/demo/.diffblue/log/user-20230922T200532.log

INFO  Finished in 2m 12s
```

---

Also, You can try for other tools like **Cucumber Framework** which is an excellent framework for writing test classes via **.feature** file in human understand syntax and capable of generating test classes based on the .feature files (it uses Gherkin language).

**Update:** I found one tool called **TackleTest-Unit** which is capable of generating Java based Unit test cases. The main thing of this tool is that it supports **Ant**.

**Github Repo:** https://github.com/konveyor/tackle-test-generator-cli

From **README.md** :

> **TackleTest-Unit** automatically generates unit test cases for Java applications. Each generated test case focuses on exercising the
> visible methods of an application class. Test generation can be done
> on a specific set of application classes or the entire application.
>
> Among its many features, TackleTest-Unit:
>
> - Supports automatic generation of test assertions: tests can be generated with or without assertions
> - Combines different coverage metrics and generates coverage reports: the supported coverage metrics include conventional code coverage
>   criteria, such as statement and branch coverage, as well as a novel
>   type-based combinatorial coverage coverage of Java methods
> - Accommodates developer-written unit test suites: it can perform coverage-driven augmentation and directed test generation to enhance
>   the coverage achieved by a given test suite
> - Supports multiple build tools: **Maven**, **Gradle**, and **Ant**

**Read the docs for more. I feel that the tool looks promising. So, you can try it.**

Comment: @Ashar Is this helpful?

Comment: it helped but can you suggest similar solution / popular tool for `ANT` based projects build.xml?

Comment: @Ashar I have updated my answer. Please verify. You can use one tool called `TackleTest-UI` and it supports Ant to be specific. Check the updated answer.